# Eclipse xdebug - skips breakpoints in PHP-CLI, but works for PHP-Apache?

Tags: php, eclipse, command-line-interface, xdebug, breakpoints

I'm running eclipse Juno with XDebug to debug php scripts.  Everything works fine when I debug as a "Web page", BUT when I debug a CLI script, Eclipse/XDebug skip right over my breakpoints.

My php.ini file uses the very same xdebug settings for both apache2 and cli:

```
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/tmp/xdebug/"
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_port = "10000"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart = Off
xdebug.remote_log = "/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.scream = On
```

While (attempting) to debug, I get the following phpinfo() results:

```
PHP Version => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2

System => Linux joomla-VirtualBox 3.2.0-26-generic-pae #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 16:45:14 UTC 2012 i686
Build Date => Jun 13 2012 17:19:38
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /tmp/zend_debug/session150485809077526207.tmp/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20090626
PHP Extension => 20090626
Zend Extension => 220090626
Zend Extension Build => API220090626,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20090626,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => disabled
IPv6 Support => enabled
Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip  
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk


This server is protected with the Suhosin Patch 0.9.10
Copyright (c) 2006-2007 Hardened-PHP Project
Copyright (c) 2007-2009 SektionEins GmbH


This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

bz2

BZip2 Support => Enabled
Stream Wrapper support => compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support => bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version => 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_call_time_pass_reference => Off => Off
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
always_populate_raw_post_data => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
asp_tags => Off => Off
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => no value => no value
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
define_syslog_variables => Off => Off
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority, => pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
exit_on_timeout => Off => Off
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs => /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
file_uploads => On => On
highlight.bg => <font style="color: #FFFFFF">#FFFFFF</font> => <font style="color: #FFFFFF">#FFFFFF</font>
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/var/www/test => .:/var/www/test
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
magic_quotes_gpc => Off => Off
magic_quotes_runtime => Off => Off
magic_quotes_sybase => Off => Off
mail.add_x_header => On => On
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 256M => 256M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 128M => 128M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 16K => 16K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
register_globals => Off => Off
register_long_arrays => Off => Off
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
safe_mode => Off => Off
safe_mode_exec_dir => no value => no value
safe_mode_gid => Off => Off
safe_mode_include_dir => no value => no value
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i  => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
serialize_precision => 17 => 17
short_open_tag => On => On
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 20M => 20M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
y2k_compliance => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

date

date/time support => enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => America/Los_Angeles

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => America/Los_Angeles => America/Los_Angeles

dba

DBA support => enabled
Supported handlers => cdb cdb_make db4 inifile flatfile 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
dba.default_handler => flatfile => flatfile

dom

DOM/XML => enabled
DOM/XML API Version => 20031129
libxml Version => 2.7.8
HTML Support => enabled
XPath Support => enabled
XPointer Support => enabled
Schema Support => enabled
RelaxNG Support => enabled

ereg

Regex Library => Bundled library enabled

exif

EXIF Support => enabled
EXIF Version => 1.4 $Id: exif.c 321634 2012-01-01 13:15:04Z felipe $
Supported EXIF Version => 0220
Supported filetypes => JPEG,TIFF

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel => UCS-2LE => UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola => UCS-2BE => UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis => no value => no value
exif.encode_unicode => ISO-8859-15 => ISO-8859-15

fileinfo

fileinfo support => enabled
version => 1.0.5-dev

filter

Input Validation and Filtering => enabled
Revision => $Revision: 321634 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
filter.default => unsafe_raw => unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags => no value => no value

ftp

FTP support => enabled

gettext

GetText Support => enabled

hash

hash support => enabled
Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b salsa10 salsa20 haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5 

iconv

iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.15

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
iconv.input_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1

json

json support => enabled
json version => 1.2.1

libxml

libXML support => active
libXML Compiled Version => 2.7.8
libXML Loaded Version => 20708
libXML streams => enabled

mbstring

Multibyte Support => enabled
Multibyte string engine => libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation => disabled

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support => enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check => On
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version => 4.7.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mbstring.detect_order => no value => no value
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.func_overload => 0 => 0
mbstring.http_input => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
mbstring.language => neutral => neutral
mbstring.strict_detection => Off => Off
mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value

mhash

MHASH support => Enabled
MHASH API Version => Emulated Support

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012

pcntl

pcntl support => enabled

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.12 2011-01-15

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar EXT version => 2.0.1
Phar API version => 1.1.1
SVN revision => $Revision: 321634 $
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
gzip compression => enabled
bzip2 compression => enabled
Native OpenSSL support => enabled


Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On

posix

Revision => $Revision: 321634 $

Reflection

Reflection => enabled
Version => $Revision: 321634 $

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user 
Registered serializer handlers => php php_binary wddx 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.bug_compat_42 => Off => Off
session.bug_compat_warn => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => Off => Off
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => Off => Off
session.entropy_file => no value => no value
session.entropy_length => 0 => 0
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 0 => 0
session.hash_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.hash_function => 0 => 0
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => /var/lib/php5 => /var/lib/php5
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.use_cookies => On => On
session.use_only_cookies => On => On
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

shmop

shmop support => enabled

SimpleXML

Simplexml support => enabled
Revision => $Revision: 321634 $
Schema support => enabled

soap

Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400

sockets

Sockets Support => enabled

SPL

SPL support => enabled
Interfaces => Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
from => no value => no value
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars => PHP_ => PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars => LD_LIBRARY_PATH => LD_LIBRARY_PATH
url_rewriter.tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent => no value => no value

sysvmsg

sysvmsg support => enabled
Revision => $Revision: 321634 $

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

wddx

WDDX Support => enabled
WDDX Session Serializer => enabled

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.7.8

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

zip

Zip => enabled
Extension Version => $Id: php_zip.c 321634 2012-01-01 13:15:04Z felipe $
Zip version => 1.9.1
Libzip version => 0.9.0

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper support => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter support => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.1.1
Linked Version => 1.2.3.4

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name
readline
sysvsem
sysvshm

Environment

Variable => Value
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL => /tmp/keyring-RhKbl6
XDG_SESSION_PATH => /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
SSH_AGENT_PID => 1423
XFILESEARCHPATH => /usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
SESSION_MANAGER => local/joomla-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1316,unix/joomla-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1316
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID => this-is-deprecated
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE => ae1261c70d1ac1b039e621b500000005-1341681427.84811-994195454
GDMSESSION => ubuntu-2d
MANDATORY_PATH => /usr/share/gconf/ubuntu-2d.mandatory.path
XDG_DATA_DIRS => /usr/share/ubuntu-2d:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
PWD => /home/joomla
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE => /home/joomla/eclipse.desktop
LOGNAME => joomla
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID => 4808
GPG_AGENT_INFO => /tmp/keyring-RhKbl6/gpg:0:1
NLSPATH => /usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
SSH_AUTH_SOCK => /tmp/keyring-RhKbl6/ssh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH => /usr/bin
SHELL => /bin/bash
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS => unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-oBhXTh59Tm,guid=a7bdcef1528a12b9a9b24b150000000c
PATH => /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS => /etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu-2d:/etc/xdg
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP => Unity
DESKTOP_SESSION => ubuntu-2d
DISPLAY => :0
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY => libappmenu.so
USER => joomla
XDEBUG_CONFIG => remote_enable=1 idekey=ECLIPSE_DBGP
HOME => /home/joomla
XAUTHORITY => /home/joomla/.Xauthority
DEFAULTS_PATH => /usr/share/gconf/ubuntu-2d.default.path
XDG_SEAT_PATH => /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
DBGP_COOKIE => 13417791168931
DBGP_IDEKEY => ECLIPSE_DBGP
LANG => en_US.UTF-8

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
_SERVER["GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL"] => /tmp/keyring-RhKbl6
_SERVER["XDG_SESSION_PATH"] => /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
_SERVER["SSH_AGENT_PID"] => 1423
_SERVER["XFILESEARCHPATH"] => /usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
_SERVER["SESSION_MANAGER"] => local/joomla-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1316,unix/joomla-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1316
_SERVER["GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID"] => this-is-deprecated
_SERVER["XDG_SESSION_COOKIE"] => ae1261c70d1ac1b039e621b500000005-1341681427.84811-994195454
_SERVER["GDMSESSION"] => ubuntu-2d
_SERVER["MANDATORY_PATH"] => /usr/share/gconf/ubuntu-2d.mandatory.path
_SERVER["XDG_DATA_DIRS"] => /usr/share/ubuntu-2d:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
_SERVER["PWD"] => /home/joomla
_SERVER["GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE"] => /home/joomla/eclipse.desktop
_SERVER["LOGNAME"] => joomla
_SERVER["GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID"] => 4808
_SERVER["GPG_AGENT_INFO"] => /tmp/keyring-RhKbl6/gpg:0:1
_SERVER["NLSPATH"] => /usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
_SERVER["SSH_AUTH_SOCK"] => /tmp/keyring-RhKbl6/ssh
_SERVER["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] => /usr/bin
_SERVER["SHELL"] => /bin/bash
_SERVER["DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"] => unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-oBhXTh59Tm,guid=a7bdcef1528a12b9a9b24b150000000c
_SERVER["PATH"] => /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
_SERVER["XDG_CONFIG_DIRS"] => /etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu-2d:/etc/xdg
_SERVER["XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"] => Unity
_SERVER["DESKTOP_SESSION"] => ubuntu-2d
_SERVER["DISPLAY"] => :0
_SERVER["UBUNTU_MENUPROXY"] => libappmenu.so
_SERVER["USER"] => joomla
_SERVER["XDEBUG_CONFIG"] => remote_enable=1 idekey=ECLIPSE_DBGP
_SERVER["HOME"] => /home/joomla
_SERVER["XAUTHORITY"] => /home/joomla/.Xauthority
_SERVER["DEFAULTS_PATH"] => /usr/share/gconf/ubuntu-2d.default.path
_SERVER["XDG_SEAT_PATH"] => /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
_SERVER["DBGP_COOKIE"] => 13417791168931
_SERVER["DBGP_IDEKEY"] => ECLIPSE_DBGP
_SERVER["LANG"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] => /var/www/test/test.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] => /var/www/test/test.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] => /var/www/test/test.php
_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"] => /var/www/test/test.php
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] => 
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] => 1341779117
_SERVER["argv"] => Array
(
    [0] => /var/www/test/test.php
)

_SERVER["argc"] => 1

PHP License
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group
and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.
```

Thanks for your help!

Mike

Comment: What happens when you turn on remote autostart?

Comment: changing xdebug.remote_autostart=On has no effect.  I ran phpinfo() in the PHP-CLI script and noted:    _SERVER["XDEBUG_CONFIG"] => remote_enable=1 idekey=ECLIPSE_DBGP.  I think idekey is supposed to be a number and remote_handler is supposed to be dbgp.

Comment: Is anyone else able to debug PHP-CLI scripts with Eclipse Juno.  I have it running fine under Eclipse Indigo, with the same php.ini, same PHP-Debug settings so I think everything is set correctly.  It's just not working in Juno... just checking if this is a bug.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Indigo + XDebug works fine, but Juno will not stop at any of my breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

While the suggestion by danip to add the xdebug configuration in php.ini is correct, an easier way to resolve this issue is to add xdebug.ini to the field "PHP ini file (optional)" in the PHP Executable information dialog.

From the debug configuration dialog, PHP script tab, choose Alternate PHP, then click the button "Installed PHP...", then add or edit the PHP executable info as mentioned.

Typically, CLI php would read the ini file in conf.d (where xdebug.ini would normally reside), but not under PHP Eclipse (PDT), hence the root cause of this problem.   PDT 3.1.1 does not yet address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on linux I specified the php.ini file and put the xdebug configuration inside it. ( xdebug was setup inside php.d folder and eclipse was not loading that)

Answer (score 0):

Today I got the same problem. 
Can fix it by simple check the option: "Use system default php.ini configuration".

[image]